# PHP Login code wont run?

Tags: php

I cannot get the PHP code to run within the HTML code.  It simply will not work and I can't figure it out. I removed the `<head></head>` part of the html and the PHP login script works again. How do I fix this?

**Here is my PHP:**

```
<?php
include("db.php");
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // username and password sent from Form
    $username   =   mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']); 
    $password   =   mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 
    $password   =   md5($password); // Encrypted Password
    $sql        =   "SELECT id FROM Users WHERE username='$username' and passcode='$password'";
    $result     =   mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $count      =   mysqli_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
    if($count==1) {
        header("location: greatjob.php");
    }
    else {
        $error  =   "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
    }
}
?>



<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="test Portal | Login" />
    <meta name="author" content="test" />

    <title>test Portal | Login</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="logintemplate/js/jquery-ui/css/no-theme/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="logintemplate/css/font-icons/entypo/css/entypo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,700,400italic">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="logintemplate/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="logintemplate/css/neon-core.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="logintemplate/css/neon-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="logintemplate/css/neon-forms.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="logintemplate/css/custom.css">

    <script src="logintemplate/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>$.noConflict();</script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="logintemplate/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->



</head>
<body class="page-body login-page login-form-fall" data-url="http://test.dev">


<!-- This is needed when you send requests via Ajax -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var baseurl = '';
</script>

<div class="login-container">

    <div class="login-header login-caret">

        <div class="login-content">

            <a href="index.html" class="logo">
                <img src="logintemplate/images/logo@2x.png" width="120" alt="" />
            </a>

            <p class="description">Dear user, log in to access the admin area!</p>

            <!-- progress bar indicator -->
            <div class="login-progressbar-indicator">
                <h3>43%</h3>
                <span>logging in...</span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="login-progressbar">
        <div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="login-form">

        <div class="login-content">

            <div class="form-login-error">
                <h3>Invalid login</h3>
                <p><?PHP echo $error; ?></p>
            </div>

            <form method="post" action="login.php" role="form" id="form_login">

                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="entypo-user"></i>
                        </div>

                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" />
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="entypo-key"></i>
                        </div>

                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" />
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-login">
                        <i class="entypo-login"></i>
                        Login In
                    </button>
                </div>  
            </form>


            <div class="login-bottom-links">

                <a href="extra-forgot-password.html" class="link">Forgot your password?</a>

                <br />

                <a href="test.com/tos">ToS</a>  - <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>


    <!-- Bottom scripts (common) -->
    <script src="logintemplate/js/gsap/main-gsap.js"></script>
    <script src="logintemplate/js/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.minimal.min.js"></script>
    <script src="logintemplate/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="logintemplate/js/joinable.js"></script>
    <script src="logintemplate/js/resizeable.js"></script>
    <script src="logintemplate/js/neon-api.js"></script>
    <script src="logintemplate/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="logintemplate/js/neon-login.js"></script>


    <!-- JavaScripts initializations and stuff -->
    <script src="logintemplate/js/neon-custom.js"></script>


    <!-- Demo Settings -->
    <script src="logintemplate/js/neon-demo.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try putting session_start(); in the very beginning of your file. The sequence should be <?php session_start(); ?> then your html and other stuff. And more over,  I cannot get the PHP code to run within the HTML code -> what does this exactly mean?

Comment: @Suyog Session_start(); is already at the top?  The PHP code doesn't run as in, I cannot get it to redirect or even read the database or anything?

Comment: It looks like the problem is the JS file.   <script src="logintemplate/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>  But i dont know what to do or how to allow it to work with it.

Comment: How do you know? Is there there a console error?

Comment: @Rasclatt error codes are not showing up even with error reporting on.

Comment: But you are saying it's because of the jQuery link, how do you know that is my question?

Comment: @Rasclatt Because when I remove the jquery link the PHP code works again.

Comment: @KarlRowe. put all the `<script>`'s in the `<head>` section even the the ones you've written at the bottom.

Comment: Well because jQuery/javascript and php are run separately (php runs first, then javascript) it is likely that the php is running fine but the jquery is interfering with the page view. Get source from the browser. The page is probably all rendered

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari Didn't work :(

Comment: @Rasclatt So what do you think the solution is then?

Comment: @KarlRowe. `echo $sql        =   "SELECT id FROM Users WHERE username='$username' and passcode='$password'";` and what do you see?

Comment: Did you look in your javascript console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: @Rasclatt No I dont get any errors at all.

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari it just says undefined values for username and password.

Comment: Is this page live somewhere to look at or just localhost?

Comment: @Rasclatt Also if you hit submit you'll see $error is undefined as well.  even though its declared to output "Your Login Name or Password is invalid" when an incorrect username and pass is inputed.

Comment: `<?php if(isset($error)) { ?><div class="form-login-error"><h3>Invalid login</h3><p><?PHP echo $error; ?></p></div><?php } ?>`

Comment: This appears to be using ajax, you are not going to be able to do what you want the way you have it here. It looks like it's ajaxing to `data/sample-login-form.php`

Comment: The reason it "works" when you remove the jQuery is because the jQuery is preventing the form from submitting normally. You need to modify the ajax page instead of this page

Comment: @Rasclatt ohhhh ok that makes sense.  So there is no fix huh?

Comment: Try changing the ID of the form to something else: `id="form_login"` to `id="form_login_test"` This may allow the form to submit normally without you having remove the jQuery entirely.

Comment: Alternately, whatever you are using, you should be able to reroute the ajax to a new login page since that one is supposedly going to `data/sample-login-form.php`

Comment: Note, if you change the Id of the form, you will not get that fancy login animations stuff that is on there by default.

Comment: @Rasclatt Thank you so much for your help!!  Answer the question, so i can check it as the best answer :) thank you thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your provided link, your site is using AJAX for login so the jQuery is preventing the form from submitting normally. To make it work do one of these:

1. Change where your ajax is pointing
2. Make your changes to the page that the AJAX is currently pointing to
3. Give the login form a different `id` like `<form id="formlogin">` and the ajax will ignore it and reload your page the way you want it to.